# Why is RAM being used up at the beginning of every epoch?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, kaggle

I am running a slightly different version of [this Tensorflow Tutorial notebook](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/image_captioning) about Image Captioning (I have only added a few Dropout Layers, used another Dataset and used another pre-trained CNN model from Keras NASNetLarge). I am running this notebook on Kaggle with GPU Accelerator enabled.

The problem I have is that, at the beginning of each epoch, about 2 GB of RAM are instantly allocated, and they remain used up for the rest of the Runtime Session.

This happens at the beginning of EVERY epoch, so I can only train my model for 4-5 epochs, after that the Runtime stops with error "Ran out of Available Memory".

I have tried disabling checkpoints, disabling prefetching and using `gc.collect()` at the end of every epoch, but it still doesn't change anything.

The code that I run for each Epoch is the following:

```
EPOCHS = 35

for epoch in range(start_epoch, EPOCHS):
    start = time.time()
    total_loss = 0

    for (batch, (img_tensor, target)) in enumerate(dataset):
        batch_loss, t_loss = train_step(img_tensor, target)
        total_loss += t_loss

        if batch % 100 == 0:
            average_batch_loss = batch_loss.numpy()/int(target.shape[1])
            print(f'Epoch {epoch+1} Batch {batch} Loss {average_batch_loss:.4f}')

    # storing the epoch end loss value to plot later
    loss_plot.append(total_loss / num_steps)


    encoder_saver = f"encoder_weights_epoch_{epoch+1}.pkl"
    decoder_saver = f"decoder_weights_epoch_{epoch+1}.pkl"
    joblib.dump(encoder.get_weights(), encoder_saver)
    joblib.dump(decoder.get_weights(), decoder_saver)

    print(f'Epoch {epoch+1} Loss {total_loss/num_steps:.6f}')
    print(f'Time taken for 1 epoch {time.time()-start:.2f} sec\n')
```

The pickle files for the weights are about 20 MB each, and they are stored on the disk, so I'm pretty certain they are not the problem. The only suspicion that I have is that for some reason the `dataset` object gets loaded again on the RAM, but I have tried disabling prefetching, with no luck. The dataset object is defined as followed:

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((img_name_train, 
 cap_train))

 # Use map to load the numpy files in parallel
 dataset = dataset.map(lambda item1, item2: tf.numpy_function(
      map_func, [item1, item2], [tf.float32, tf.int64]),
      num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)

 # Shuffle and batch
 dataset = dataset.shuffle(BUFFER_SIZE).batch(BATCH_SIZE)
 dataset = dataset.prefetch(buffer_size=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
```

Haven't changed anything in that. Also the `train_step` function just computes the gradients of loss and applies them through the optimizer (I also didn't change that one as well)

Do you know what could be causing that to happen??

Thanks for any help.

Comment: To help with code, code needs to be provided

Comment: The link I have provided is a notebook. That is the exact same notebook I am using on Kaggle, except with the extra Dropout Layer, the different images, and the NASNetLarge Model. Dropout Layer obviously doesn't add anything, and the CNN model and the images dataset use the exact same code, but with different download link. So I guess I haven't changed 99.9% of the notebook.

Comment: Arguably vast majority of issues in code come from what was modified, no matter how small. Please do not expect SO members to jump to external resource and go through some tutorial to see the issue you are observing. To ask a good question (which has a change of getting a good answer) one needs to provide *minimal, working example that reproduces the issue*, and is a responsibility of the question author.

Comment: You are right..

Comment: Ok, I posted the parts of the code, that I think are the most probable to cause the issue, if you think there is anything else that might be the problem, let me know please.